# JavaScript экспорт данных с таблицы в файл excel

Tags: javascript, php, html

Проблема заключается в том, что не можно загрузить данные таблицы в файл excel.

Мой код:

```
<table id="my-table" class="table table-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('my-table')">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button>

<?php $this->registerJs("
                    function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
            var downloadLink;
            var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

            // Specify file name
            filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

            // Create download link element
            downloadLink = document.createElement('a');

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
                    type: dataType
                });
                navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
            }else{
                // Create a link to the file
                downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

                // Setting the file name
                downloadLink.download = filename;

                //triggering the function
                downloadLink.click();
            }
        }
    ");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: table.innerHTML
    }
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

```html
<h1>tableToExcel Demo</h1>
<table id="my-table" class="table table-dark table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('my-table')" value="Export HTML Table To Excel">
```

Взял [отсюда](https://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/43101-ehksport-html-table-v-excel.html)

Comment: Возникает следующая ошибка index:558 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.btnExport.onclick

Comment: Все исправил, все работает